# Create non-overlapping split of an array of elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, time-series

I have an array of data `X` which contains `N` number of elements that are recorded in time. So the array of elements represents a time series. I want to split the time series to create non-overlapping sequences of fixed length `L=500`. This can be considered as the window size. To do it manually is very tedious which I tried to do below. There is another problem which is that the elements in `X` can be of different length i.e., `N` can have 90000 elements, then again it can have 1400 elements. But `N >L`. How can I create sequences of length `L` for all different `X` in an elegant manner which works for all lengths of `X`? This is what I tried to do but got lost in the calculation. Shall appreciate help.

```
N = 90000;  %this varies for different data X

L = 500; % this is fixed
X = rand(N,1);
nSplits = N/L;

%Worked out example
X1 = X(1:L,:);
X2 = X(L+1:2L,:);
X3 = X(2L+1:2L+1+L,:); %AND SO ON TILL nSplit number of data vectors are created from X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mat2cell` to split up your vector.

```
N = 9023;  %this varies for different data X
L = 500; % this is fixed
X = rand(N,1);
nSplits = ceil(N/L); % we need nSplit segments
sz=L*ones(nSplits,1); % assume all are full, sizes for the segments
sz(end)=N-(nSplits-1)*L %Fix size of last one, in case less than L are left over
Y=mat2cell(X,sz); %Split it
```